# eBay Trading API AddFixedPriceItem returns 'Input data is invalid. Input data for tag <Item.ShippingDetails> is invalid' error

Tags: php, ebay-api

How to list shipping details in UK or France using eBay AddFixedPriceItem API call? Here is my current code, that returns error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>***</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
    <Item>
        <Country>UK</Country>
        <Currency>GBP</Currency>
        <ShippingDetails>
            <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
            <ShippingServiceOptions>
                <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
                <ShippingService>DHLExpressWorldwide</ShippingService>
                <FreeShipping>true</FreeShipping>
                <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost currencyID="EUR">0.00</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
            </ShippingServiceOptions>
        </ShippingDetails>
        <Site>UK</Site>
    </Item>
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct value to use in the ShippingService field is UK_DHLExpressWorldwide

Comment: Thanks for your response. But still i'm facing same issue. i just listout products for UK country passing this sandbox method.  Is this right? because i passed sandbox.com
https://api.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/api.dll